# Accessing tuple from within an enum

Tags: rust

I have a Rust enum defined like this

```
enum MyFirstEnum {
    TupleType(f32, i8, String),
    StuctType {varone: i32, vartwo: f64},
    NewTypeTuple(i32),
    SomeVarName
}
```

I have the following code:

```
let mfe: MyFirstEnum = MyFirstEnum::TupleType(3.14, 1, "Hello".to_string());
```

I'm following the Rust documentation and this looks fine. I don't need to define everything in the enum, but how would I go about accessing the mid element in the enum tuple?

`mfe.TupleType.1` and `mfe.1` don't work when I add them to a `println!`

I know Rust provides the facility to do pattern matching to obtain the value, but if I changed the code to define the other variants within the enum, the code to output a particular variant would quickly become a mess.

Is there a simple way to output the variant of the tuple (or any other variant) in the enum?

Comment: Note that the explicit type (`let mfe: MyFirstEnum`) is unnecessary. You've already specified the type on the right-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: *if I changed the code to define the other variants within the enum, the code to output a particular variant would quickly become a mess* — Can you expand a bit more what you mean by this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a common misconception: enum variants are **not** their own types (at least in Rust 1.9). Therefore when you create a variable like this:

```
let value = MyFirstEnum::TupleType(3.14, 1, "Hello".to_string());
```

The fact that it's a specific variant is immediately "lost". You will need to pattern match to prevent accessing the enum as the wrong variant. You *may* prefer to use an `if let` statement instead of a match:

```
if let MyFirstEnum::TupleType(f, i, s) = value {
     // Values available here
     println!("f: {:?}", f);
}
```

Comment: [This is a proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450) to make enum variants a type, but there is no decision yet, and certainly won't appear before 1.11.

Comment: @kennytm thank you for the link, I was too lazy to dig it up. This is one of the potential upcoming Rust features that I'm super excited for.

Comment: Oh well. This decision may be an explanation, but it is still not very clear. It would be better to show the solution as an example of code, rather than in pieces. This decision was not clear to me the first time.

Comment: If anyone wants to track the progress of enum variants as types, the [new RFC is here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593).

Answer (score 3):

Example solution:

```
enum MyFirstEnum {
    TupleType(f32, i8, String),
   // StuctType { varone: i32, vartwo: f64 },
  //  NewTypeTuple(i32),
  //  SomeVarName,
}

fn main() {
    let mfe: MyFirstEnum = MyFirstEnum::TupleType(3.14, 1, "Hello".to_string());
    let MyFirstEnum::TupleType(value, id, text) = &mfe;
    println!("[{}; {}; {}]", value, id, text);

//or
    match &mfe {
        MyFirstEnum::TupleType(value, id, text) => {
            println!("[{}; {}; {}]", value, id, text);
        }
       // _ => {}
    }

}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3a1069965c9e3862f485156d554adda5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: This example works, but I was confused that the 3 vars in the println!() weren't preceded by the enum. It should be noted that the reason it works is "destructuring" (covered in the Rust book).

Comment: for this example i prefer Destructing over `if let` or `match`