# Rust error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `iteration_index`

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

I have two vectors of [`itertools::MinMaxResult`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/enum.MinMaxResult.html). I need to iterate through the first vector, and for each element, iterate through the second vector, checking if the minimum of the first vector is equal to the maximum of any elements of the second vector, and vice versa. Here is an MCVE of what I tried:

```rust
use itertools::MinMaxResult; // itertools = "0.8.0"
use itertools::MinMaxResult::*;

pub fn mcve() -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {

    // dummy variables to make the MCVE compile
    let num_rows = 0;
    let num_cols = 0;
    let row_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult<&u64>> = vec![];
    let col_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult<&u64>> = vec![];

    // Problematic code:
    (0..num_rows)
            .flat_map(|row_index| {
                (0_usize..num_cols).filter_map(|col_index| {
                    match (row_minmax[row_index], col_minmax[col_index]) {
                        (MinMax(a, _b), MinMax(_c, d)) if a == d =>
                            Some((row_index, col_index)),
                        (MinMax(_a, b), MinMax(c, _d)) if b == c =>
                            Some((row_index, col_index)),
                        _ => None,
                    }
                })
            })
            .collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>()
}
```

[Link to the Playground with full code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c67c37b5172388c1f8830ed871b4397d)

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `row_index`,
which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:15:48
   |
15 |                 (0_usize..num_cols).filter_map(|col_index| {
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive 
                                                    borrowed value `row_index`
16 |                     match (row_minmax[row_index], col_minmax[col_index]) {
   |                                       --------- `row_index` is borrowed here
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
15 | /                 (0_usize..num_cols).filter_map(|col_index| {
16 | |                     match (row_minmax[row_index], col_minmax[col_index]) {
17 | |                         (MinMax(a, _b), MinMax(_c, d)) if a == d => 
                                   Some((row_index, col_index)),
18 | |                         (MinMax(_a, b), MinMax(c, _d)) if b == c => 
                                   Some((row_index, col_index)),
19 | |                         _ => None,
20 | |                     }
21 | |                 })
   | |__________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `row_index` 
(and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
15 |                 (0_usize..num_cols).filter_map(move |col_index| {
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I add a `move`, as the compiler suggests, I get *twice as many* errors, so that doesn't help. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: `row_minmax[row_index]:MinMax` This is not valid. I suggest you read [the chapter of The Book about `enum`s and pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It's supposed index (row_index) a vector (row_minmax) and get the 0 element of the MinMax tuple. That's the plan, anyway

Comment: @Alex But what is the colon `:` doing there? It's definitely not a type ascription. It doesn't look like anything at all, it's just unparsable stream of tokens. And it also doesn't look like a typo either, because you repeated it twice...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I thought it was supposed to get the MinMax out of the MinMaxResult enum. I'm very new to this.

Comment: @Alex the enum can be either one of 3 variants. You can't just ignore the 2 that you don't like like this.

Comment: @mcarton Ok, would you mind being a bit more descriptive about how this can be done. I'm very new to rust

Comment: Did you mean something like `match (row_minmax[row_idx], col_minmax[col_idx]) { (MinMax(a, _b), MinMax(_c, d)) => /* do sth with 'a' and 'd' */ }`? Or maybe `if let (MinMax(a, _), MinMax(_, d)) = (row_minmax[row_idx], col_minmax[col_idx]) { /* do sth. with 'a' and 'd' */ }`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yep, that looks promising

Comment: Does anybody want to bother explaining the reason for the close votes, and the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, and I retracted my close vote because I decided it was the wrong reason. However, when you're having trouble, if your normal course of action is to *invent syntax* and ask on SO why it doesn't work, you're likely to have a bad time. `enum`s are explained in the book and it tells you that you have to use `match` to get values out.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Accessing tuple from within an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37516448/3650362)

Comment: @trentcl I appreciate your explanation, but in my defence, I looked at this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html which does give the example: `Coin::Penny`. I appreciate that I was incorrect, but I didn't completely pluck the syntax out of thin air.

Comment: @Alex I voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking", because the code contains variations of `row_minmax[row_index]:MinMax.0` multiple times, which looks like an meaningless token sequence. While I didn't downvote, the reason seems obvious: 1) it's impossible to envision what one could possibly have *researched* to come up with this character sequence -> *"does not show research effort"*; 2) As already explained, it's *"unclear"*; 3) The probability that anyone else will come up with this or similar character sequence is virtually zero, so this question is likely *"not useful"*.

Comment: @Alex Can you please point out at least one occurrence of a single standing `:` separating two expressions in the entire book chapter that you just linked? Or anything at least vaguely similar to `row_minmax[row_index]:MinMax.0`?

Comment: It would have been a little more understandable, then, if you had written `row_minmax[row_index]::MinMax.0`. Even though it's not correct (and demonstrates some kind of confusion about what enum variants are), it's not as completely out of left field as `:`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm not going to argue with you. It was clearly a mistake. If I knew the correct syntax, I wouldn't be asking a question, would I?

Comment: @trentcl Yes, I did try that, and cargo complained, so I tried with a single colon, and cargo complained. I just posted the second iteration, for which I apologise, but I did try the former first.

Comment: @Alex I'm not trying to argue with anyone, I'm just responding to the little inbox notifications in a hopefully somewhat helpful way. Are you sure that you posted the changes of your "second iteration"? There are no edits on this post, and no recent changes. Was the hint with `if let (MinMax(a, b), MinMax(c, d)) = (row[idx], col[some_other_idx]) { ... }` helpful in any way, or have you just ignored that? I think this question could be greatly improved if it had an [mcve]`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, sorry, when I say second iteration, I mean when I was writing the code myself, on my machine. I first tried with `::`, and it failed, so then I tried with `:`, and it failed, so then I went to SO, and I happened to paste the second guess into my question.
Your suggestion was very helpful (I did post 'Yep, that looks promising' underneath it), so thank you very much for that. I am still getting problems with the borrow checker, but it has fixed the immediate problem in this question. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex Well, if you are getting borrow-checker errors, then it means that you definitely got through the parsing and the symbol resolution phase, so it would be really great if you could edit the question and provide the updated code together with the borrow-checker errors. *That* would be the right way to get rid of downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Ok, will do.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I've added the rest of the function code in a rust playground, as I think the borrow error comes from further up in the code than this question.

Comment: @Alex In the future, please provide all the necessary details in your question. Links to the Playground are a nice extra, but it's insufficient. I now extracted an MCVE out of your code, and also updated the Playground gist. It will now probably get closed as a duplicate of something, but this is roughly what's expected when someone requests an MCVE (or rather, you shouldn't wait until someone downvotes and asks for MCVE, just provide it right away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked gist has a whole bunch of the typical "wrestling with the borrow-checker" errors. Here is how to solve them:

- use `move` as the compiler proposes, but make sure that all moved values implement `Copy`.
- Iteration indices of type `usize` already implement `Copy`, so there is nothing to do here.
- The vectors are problematic, so just take immutable references of them, and pass the immutable references into the closures instead.
- Your `into_par_iter` causes an unrelated ownership problem. Just use `par_iter` instead, then you will iterate over references, not the actual values, and you will not destroy your matrix while you are iterating over it.

This here compiles:

```rust
use itertools::MinMaxResult; // itertools = "0.8.0"
use itertools::MinMaxResult::*;
use itertools::Itertools;
use rayon::prelude::*; // rayon = "1.0.3"

pub fn find_saddle_points(input: &[Vec<u64>]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let flattened_matrix: Vec<(&u64)> = input.into_par_iter().flatten().collect();
    if flattened_matrix.is_empty() {
        vec![]
    } else {
        let num_rows = input.len();
        let num_cols = input[0].len();

        let row_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult<&u64>> = input
            .iter()
            .map(|row| row.iter().minmax())
            .collect::<Vec<MinMaxResult<&u64>>>();

        let input_tranpose: Vec<Vec<u64>> = (0_usize..num_cols)
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(|col_index| {
                (0_usize..num_rows)
                    .map(|row_index| input[row_index][col_index])
                    .collect::<Vec<u64>>()
            })
            .collect();

        // don't take ownership! 
        // Use `par_iter` instead, then `col` will be a reference,
        // and the borrow-checker is happy.
        let col_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult<&u64>> = input_tranpose
            .par_iter()   
            .map(|col| col.iter().minmax())
            .collect();

        let rmm_ref = &row_minmax;
        let cmm_ref = &col_minmax;
        (0_usize..num_rows)
            .flat_map(|row_index| {
                (0_usize..num_cols).filter_map(move |col_index| {
                    match (rmm_ref[row_index], cmm_ref[col_index]) {
                        (MinMax(a, _b), MinMax(_c, d)) if a == d => 
                            Some((row_index, col_index)),
                        (MinMax(_a, b), MinMax(c, _d)) if b == c => 
                            Some((row_index, col_index)),
                        _ => None,
                    }
                })
            })
            .collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>()
    }
}

fn main(){}
```