# Why may a closure outlive the current function by borrowing a u32?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

I'm getting

> error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `row_nr`, which is owned by the current function

I would not expect this, since `row_nr` is a `u32`, so I'd expect it to be copied rather than moved:

```rust
fn get_neighbours(values: &Vec<Vec<u32>>, row: usize, col: usize) -> Vec<u32> {
    vec![
        values.get(row - 1).and_then(|cols| cols.get(col)),
        values.get(row).and_then(|cols| cols.get(col - 1)),
        values.get(row).and_then(|cols| cols.get(col + 1)),
        values.get(row + 1).and_then(|cols| cols.get(col)),
    ].into_iter().filter_map(|value_opt| value_opt.map(|value| *value)).collect()
}

fn get_points(values: Vec<Vec<u32>>) -> Vec<(u32, Vec<u32>)> {
    values
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(row_nr, columns)| {
            columns.iter().enumerate().map(|(column_nr, height)| {
                let neighbours = get_neighbours(&values, row_nr, column_nr);
                (*height, neighbours)
            })
        }).collect()
}
```

Full error message:

```
  --> src/lib.rs:16:44
   |
16 |             columns.iter().enumerate().map(|(column_nr, height)| {
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `row_nr`
17 |                 let neighbours = get_neighbours(&values, row_nr, column_nr);
   |                                                          ------ `row_nr` is borrowed here
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:16:13
   |
16 | /             columns.iter().enumerate().map(|(column_nr, height)| {
17 | |                 let neighbours = get_neighbours(&values, row_nr, column_nr);
18 | |                 (*height, neighbours)
19 | |             })
   | |______________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `row_nr` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
16 |             columns.iter().enumerate().map(move |(column_nr, height)| {
   |                                            ++++
```

See also [on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%0Afn%20get_neighbours(values%3A%20%26Vec%3CVec%3Cu32%3E%3E%2C%20row%3A%20usize%2C%20col%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20Vec%3Cu32%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20vec!%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values.get(row%20-%201).and_then(%7Ccols%7C%20cols.get(col))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values.get(row).and_then(%7Ccols%7C%20cols.get(col%20-%201))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values.get(row).and_then(%7Ccols%7C%20cols.get(col%20%2B%201))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values.get(row%20%2B%201).and_then(%7Ccols%7C%20cols.get(col))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D.into_iter().filter_map(%7Cvalue_opt%7C%20value_opt.map(%7Cvalue%7C%20*value)).collect()%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20get_points(values%3A%20Vec%3CVec%3Cu32%3E%3E)%20-%3E%20Vec%3C(u32%2C%20Vec%3Cu32%3E)%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20values%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.iter()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.enumerate()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.flat_map(%7C(row_nr%2C%20columns)%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20columns.iter().enumerate().map(%7C(column_nr%2C%20height)%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20neighbours%20%3D%20get_neighbours(%26values%2C%20row_nr%2C%20column_nr)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(*height%2C%20neighbours)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).collect()%0A%7D%0A).

Now, the error suggest using `move`, but that becomes problematic because I'd only like to pass a reference to the `values` Vec (which I don't think should outlive the closure, because `get_neighbours` takes `u32`s from that Vec and thus should make copies too, I think?).

I presume I'm misunderstanding lifetimes here. I'd appreciate any insights on what I'm misinterpreting. I looked at a couple of related questions, but they seem to either resolve it using a `move` (which, as mentioned above, I think I should (be able to) avoid?), or have multiple borrow checker issues, making it hard for me to understand which applies ones to me (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54600044/859631)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would not expect this, since `row_nr` is a `u32`, so I'd expect it to be copied rather than moved

This expectation is correct, *assuming it were moved* in the first place. In this case it's not moved, it's borrowed, because by default closures borrow values from their environment. To request a `move`, which will for `u32` indeed result in a copy, you need to use the `move` keyword explicitly.

As you discovered, when you just use `move`, you also move `values`, which doesn't compile and is anyway not what you want. The standard Rust idiom to move only one value into the closure is to use `move` and explicitly borrow the captured variables you *don't* want moved (in yout case `values`). For example, this compiles:

```
.flat_map(|(row_nr, columns)| {
    columns.iter().enumerate().map({
        let values = &values;
        move |(column_nr, height)| {
            let neighbours = get_neighbours(values, row_nr, column_nr);
            (*height, neighbours)
        }
    })
})
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d782a0f1fb9c13f9eec1c39488c4baf5)

As for your titular question of why may a closure outlive the current function: Note that the "current function" in the error message refers to the outer closure, the one passed to `flat_map()`. Since the inner closure becomes part of the iterator returned by `map()`, and the outer closure immediately returns that iterator, it is trivially true that the inner closure does outlive the "current function" and that it cannot be allowed to borrow either `row_nr` or `columns`. (But borrowing `values` is perfectly fine because `values` outlives both closures.)